# G.C.D. of polynomials using primary decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

It might be very silly question to ask but I am unable to solve it. So I am reading text *Linear Algebra* by *Hoffman-Kunze*. I just read primary decomposition of polynomial and after that author states the following.

> g.c.d. of a finite number of non-scalar monic polynomials $f_i$'s is obtained by combining all those monic primes which occur simultaneously in their factorizations and exponent to which each prime is to be taken is the largest for which the corresponding prime power is a factor of each $f_i$

I understand why this should work intuitively but not getting it mathematically.

The g.c.d. '$d$' of polynomials $p_1,\cdots, p_n$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is defined as the monic generator of the ideal $p_1 \mathbb{F}[x]+\cdots +p_n\mathbb{F}[x]$. One corollary characterizes
this g.c.d.(monic generator) by following two conditions.
(i) $d$ is in the ideal $p_1 \mathbb{F}[x]+\cdots +p_n\mathbb{F}[x]$.
(ii) $d$ divides each of the polynomials $p_i$.

So coming back to question, I wanted to verify above two conditions for the g.c.d. obtained by using primary decomposition theorem. Condition (ii) is easily verified but I am stuck on verification of (i) condition. 
Thanks.

Comment: Take a simple example. What is the gcd of $f=x^2-3x+2$ and $g=x^2-4x+3$ in $K[x]$? The prime decompositions are $f=(x-1)(x-2)$ and $g=(x-1)(x-3)$. So we have ${\rm gcd}(f,g)=x-1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes Sir, I understand why this should work but I am not able to derive it mathematically.. I mean to show $x-1$ is g.c.d. of $f$ and $g$, we should show it is monic generator of the ideal $fK[x]+gK[x]$ or we should show it satisfies two conditions $1.$ $x-1$ divides $f$ and $g$ and $2.$ It is in the ideal $fK[x]+gK[x]$. First condition is easy to verify, but I am stuck on second. Can you help me how to show first criterion or second condition of second criterion. Also please let me know if there is any other condition to verify g.c.d.

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote by $d$ the polynomial described in paragraph from the book, and for each $i$ write $f_{i}=dp_{i}$ for some polynomial $p_{i}$. Now consider $M$ the ideal generated by $p_{1},...p_{n}$. By the corollary there is a unique monic polynomial $d_{2}$ such that

- $d_{2}$ is in the ideal M.
- $d_{2}$ divides each of the polynomials $p_{i}$

But from the construction of $d$ we see that the only monic polynomial which divides each of the polynomials $p_{i}$ is $1$ (by the primary decomposition, for no prime factor appears in every polynomial $p_{i}$), thus $d_{2}=1$. Since $d_{2}$ is in $M$, there exist polynomials $q_{1},...q_{n}$ such that
$$d_{2}=1=p_{1}q_{1}+...+p_{n}q_{n}$$
which implies
$$d=dp_{1}q_{1}+...+dp_{n}q_{n}=f_{1}q_{1}+...+f_{n}q_{n}$$
i.e. $d$ is in the ideal generated by $f_{1},...f_{n}$. Now since $d$ divides each of the polynomials $f_{i}$ the corollary tells us that $d$ is the g.c.d. of $f_{1},...f_{n}$.